# Double delay in jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Is there a way to delay the calling of a JavaScript function until two criteria are met?

I have a `slideUp()` animation and a `.get()` function that start at the same time, but either one could finish first. I want a function to be called when both have completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to keep track, either a counter or (my preferred approach) flags for all relevant information.

```
var slideDone, getDone;

$("#foo").slideUp(function() {
    slideDone = true;
    nextThing();
});
$.get({
    // ...
    success: function() {
        getDone = true;
        nextThing();
    }
});

function nextThing() {
    if (slideDone && getDone) {
        // Do the next thing
    }
}
```

Now, obviously my two conditions above are very artificial, but I find that most of the time when this comes up in my real work, I have actual information I can use for the check and so don't resort to artificial conditions.

Or a counter:

```
var counter = 0;

++counter;
$("#foo").slideUp(function() {
    nextThing();
});
++counter;
$.get({
    // ...
    success: function() {
        nextThing();
    }
});

function nextThing() {
    if (--counter === 0) {
        // Do the next thing
    }
}
```

To someone used to multi-threaded programming, that looks like a race condition (what if the `slideUp` completes before we *start* the `get`?), but it's not one in JavaScript on browsers, which is single-threaded (barring the use of [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), which use a syntax that wouldn't apply to the above anyway).

If you find this coming up a lot, you could of course always isolate the logic (not that there's a *lot* of it, but...) into an object and reuse it.

Comment: You should wrap the whole thing in a `(function(){ })()` to keep the global scope clean

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Some kind of scope is implied. I'm not saying this is top-level script, but rather what he might do in his function where he's doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple boolean variable which both delegate methods have acesss to and check whether the previous method has executed.

This way you can check in your delegate functions if the previous function has completed and execute some method.

T.J. Crowders answer includes some good example code of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's Deferred Object:
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

It's actually perfect for what you need. You can set a function to only execute when all the deferred objects bound to it get resolved. Some of jQuery's native functions return a deferred object by default such as the $.ajax and I believe animations as well (the latest version of jQuery at least)

Read the docs, it'll do a much better job at explaining it than I could.